# Biblatex entry renumbering and prefixing

Tags: biblatex, numbering, moderncv

I am using moderncv and am trying to make split my publication list. Each type (i.e. book, article, etc) should have its own subbibliography and the numbering should restart from 1 at each subbiblio and be prefixed with the same letter. Book subbiblio should have a B and articles should have a C.

My example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\usepackage[style=numeric, defernumbers=true, sorting=ydnt, url=false, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
%% Character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%% Adjust the page margins
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm]{geometry}
    \geometry{textheight=700pt}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{label1,
        author = {First Name and author2},
        title = {Title},
        journaltitle = {Journal},
        date = {2017},
    }
    @misc{label2,
        author = {author2 and author3},
        title = {Title},
        date = {2016}
    }
    @misc{label3,
        author = {author1 and author3},
        title = {Title3},
        date = {2015}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\firstname{Bla} % Your first name
\familyname{Bla} % Your last name
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle % Print the CV title
\section{Publications}
\nocite{*}
\subsection{Journals}
\printbibliography[type=article,heading=none]
\printbibliography[title={Miscellaneous},type=misc,heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}
```

Executing this, I get the following: 
[image]

I would very much appreciate an advice on how to do numbering restart and prefixes so that I get e.g. [B.1], [B.2] and [C.1], [C.2] when listing the bib items. Please, note that all my bib entries are not statically defined in the tex but come from a bib file that might be changing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about something like `\newrefcontext[labelprefix=A]
\printbibliography[type=article,heading=none]
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=M]
\printbibliography[title={Miscellaneous},type=misc,heading=subbibliography]`

Answer (score 1):

You can get letter prefixes with `\newrefcontext`

```
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=A]
\printbibliography[type=article,heading=none]
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=M]
\printbibliography[title={Miscellaneous},type=misc,heading=subbibliography]
```

would prefix all `@article`s with "A" and all `@misc`s with "M". Numbering automatically restarts at 1.