# Custom citation label

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, xetex, pdftex

I have been trying to cite different publication types using different labels for each. For instance, having the following bib file

```
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}

@article{Anonymous:2013,
Author = {Anonymous, Arthur},
Journal = {Somewhere},
Pages = {46-54},
Title = {Arthur's article},
Volume = {25 (2013)},
Year = {2013},
sorttitle = {b}}

@article{Anonymous:2012c,

Author = {Anonymous, Arthur},
Journal = {Somewhere else},
Pages = {6-12},
Title = {Last words},
Volume = {43 (2012)},
Year = {2012},
sorttitle = {c}}

@book{Anonymous:2012a,
Address = {Someplace},
Author = {Anonymous, Arthur},
Publisher = {Nobody},
Title = {Book by Arthur},
Year = {2012},
sorttitle = {a}}

\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{references.bib}
```

How can I produce a citation list with biblatex as follows:

## Books

[B1] A. Anonymous, Book by Arthur, bla bla

## Articles

[J2] A. Anonymous, Arthur's article, Somewhere, 2013, bla bla

[J1] A. Anonymous, Last words, Somewhere else, 2012, bla bla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily add a prefix to a numeric/alphabetic label with the `labelprefix` option to `\newrefcontext`. `labelprefix` needs `defernumbers` enabled globally. The bibliography can be split by type as described in [Sectioning bibliography by type of referred item](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20246/35864) with the `type` option to `\printbibliography`.

An entry in a bibliography always applies the current refcontext. Citations apply the last refcontext (last for implementational simplicity) in which an entry was printed in a bibliography

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber, defernumbers]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,baez/article,nussbaum,aksin}

\printbibheading
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=B]
\printbibliography[type=book, title=Books, heading=subbibliography]
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=J]
\printbibliography[type=article, title=Articles, heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}
```

[image: Split bibliographies with different prefixes for their labels.]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/434348/35864 describes something similar, but the question already had the split and it made sense to expand slightly on the short answer there.

Comment: Thanks for that answer! One detail is the following. How can change counting such that it starts from the oldest to lattest? In your MWE, the order is correct, however the numbering should be

[J3] Ozge
[J2] John
[J1] Emma

Comment: @HSS Argh, I missed that. Sorry. Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/367163/35864 help?

Comment: @HSS In that case we should probably close this question as a duplicate to avoid confusion. Is that alright with you?

Comment: Yes, that is fine